# is "up *something*!" an idiom?

Tags: idioms

I overheard someone say "up *something*!" wherein *something* is a variable for... whatever.

Is this an English language idiom?

If so, in what dialect of English?

What are some examples of it's usage?

Comment: 'Up the Arsenal!' may still be heard, but it sounds dated and doesn't really work with most sports clubs (lacking the 'the'). 'Up the women!' and 'Up the workers!' were once quite common, but sound rather comedic (and _possibly_ comical) nowadays. There were comedies utilising these expressions as titles. It's not usually heard nowadays except in lubricated registers.

Comment: As @Edwin implies, what the *something* was is actually quite important. For example, there is also "Up yours!" which means soemthing quite different from "Up the workers".

Comment: In the US, "up *some noun*" is generally taken as a variation of "up your ass", which is essentially a variation on "fuck you".

Comment: Up can mean to increase or raise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's heard in Ireland for supporting county teams, as in:

[image: Up Mayo]

[Source @Nora_McNeely](http://mayogaablog.com/?p=13293)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? This answers all 3 of OP's questions. Yes it's an English language idiom, yes it's heard in Ireland, and here's an example of its usage - alive and well! And it quotes the source in case anyone wants to read further. So up yours.

Comment: Up voted. There's a similar usage recorded in (IIRC) Nigel Rees' "Graffiti Rules OK", where a graffitist had drawn up various categories (Sport, Politics, etc) and then written "Up the reds!" under each.

Comment: Delightful medium. But the dye runs. (We saw multicoloured sheep on our recent trip round Ireland. I'd always wondered how they made those multicoloured cardies.)